# Buscador de archivos locales en pagina web

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

soy nuevo en esto,
El problema o duda que tengo es que necesito hacer un buscador de archivos locales.
Tengo una carpeta que a su vez tiene mas carpetas y dentro de estas tengo archivos.
Lo que quiero es, por decir que busque dentro de una ruta, y busque dentro de todas las carpetas el archivo que yo escribi en el buscador.

Vaya algo como el explorador de carpetas de windows pero llevarlo a una pagina web.

No se si exista alguna forma de hacer esto ya sea en php en javascript o alguna otra forma para pagina web.
Gracias
¿Alguna idea o ayuda?

**Actualizacion**

Hice que funcionara pero ahora necesito poder abrir ese archivo o que se pueda seleccionar.

Ademas de que sale toda la dirreccion completa y necesito que solo salga el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <form action="tu_archivo.php" method="post" >
          <input type="text" name="n_archivo" />
          <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
          </form>
        
<?php
      $archivo = $_POST['n_archivo'];
         function buscar($dir,&$archivo_buscar){  
        if ( is_dir($dir) )
         {
          // Se hace el recorrido d elos directorios
          $d=opendir($dir); 
          while( $archivo = readdir($d) )
          {
            if ( $archivo!="." AND $archivo!=".."  )
            {
              if ( is_file($dir.'/'.$archivo) )
                 {
                    // Identifica si es un archivo
                    if ( $archivo == $archivo_buscar  )
                      {
                        return ($dir.'/'.$archivo);
                    } 
                }
                if ( is_dir($dir.'/'.$archivo) )
                {
                     // Es un directorio y vuelve a llamar
                     $r=buscar($dir.'/'.$archivo,$archivo_buscar);
                     if ( basename($r) == $archivo_buscar )
                     {
                          return $r;
                    } 
                }
            }         
        }            
    }
    return FALSE;
}
echo buscar('C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\Carpetas1',$archivo);
echo $archivo;
?>
```

Comment: Hola Víctor, una vez envías al script php los datos del formulario con lo que quieres buscar, puedes utilizar la función scandir. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php

Comment: Hola, esto tambien ayuda a buscar dentro de las otras carpetas?

Comment: Scandir devuelve un array con el contenido de la carpeta que pasas como parámetro, posteriormente puedes saber si es un directorio con is_dir, puedes ver el ejemplo en la nota 158 de https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de dos formas, enviar el formulario a un fichero php, que sería crear un archivo php al que tu has llamado tu_archivo.php, o bien realizar un ajax con javascript y devolver una estructura json con los datos que devuelve tu_archivo.php https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Ya, pero hara necesito que ese archivo se pueda abrir o seleccionar de alguna manera

Comment: Creo que este ejemplo te puede valer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363904/how-would-i-scan-a-directory-to-make-links-to-pdfs-using-php

Comment: @VictorA En su función buscar tiene dos argumentos ($ dir y $ archivo_buscar) pero en su formulario solo tiene una entrada para la búsqueda: entonces, ¿quiere que el usuario escriba solo el nombre del archivo para buscar o el nombre del directorio también?